# Update 15 digit record id to 18 digit record id

Tags: administration

How to update **15 digit** record id to **18 digit** record id, currently when i click on any account record in URL we can see **15 digit** record id but as per my user requirement i need to show **18 digit** instead of **15 digit.**
is it possible?

Comment: You're not going to have an easy time modifying the url on a standard page if that is what you are after.

Answer (score 4):

If you just need a one-off conversion, you can use a tool like this

https://www.adminbooster.com/tool/15to18

If you want it in real time and shown and/or accessible on the record itself, you can use the `CASESAFEID()` function within a formula field

You would want to create a formula field on the Account object of type Text, then the formula is just

```
CASESAFEID(Id)
```

Then you can see below how it gives you the 18 digit id rather than the 15 digit in the url.

[image]

Comment: and if you need it in the code  (String) Id.valueOf(inputId);